# How do I export a BLOB varbinary(max) column to a CSV or excel without using xp_cmdshell?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, blob

I am forbidden from using xp_cmdshell. I have a table in a SQL Server 2008R2 instance that has a varbinary(max) BLOB column that I need to ouput into a CSV or Excel format. Not sure how to do this. I can log into the server remotely and run a SQLCmd off the command prompt but I've never converted this type of data before so I'm not sure of the syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [BCP.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.110).aspx) instead.  it is a command line tool, designed exactly for what you want to do.  sample:

```
bcp.exe [db1].[dbo].[table1] out file1.csv -n -T -S"server1"
```

If you wanted a single row per file (i won't ask why you want to do this), the most optimal way would be to use script (powershell/wscript/jscript/etc.) and parse your file, line by line.

Another non-optimal way is to generate TSQL that loops through every single row (probably with a cursor), printing out your bcp.exe statement via queryout.  This assumes you can have some sort of key defined that will isolate a single row.  see pseudocode below:

```
-- create and wrap your cursor around this
select 'bcp.exe "select * from dbo.table1 where pkcol = ' + cast(@pkcol as varchar) + ' queryout file1.csv -n -T -S"server1"'
from dbo.table1
where col1 = @pkcol
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. If I wanted to output one file per row that has BLOB data, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You could write a query to generate your bcp.exe, using queryout option instead.  see edit above.

Comment: Cursor successfully generated scripts for each row that had blob data but the csv or excel files that are generated are gibberish and unreadable. Our databases are encrypted via TDE. Wondering if that might be causing the issue?

Comment: Using a -C switch turns the varbinary data into orignaly blob column data in the excel or csv file. While readable it's not the actual file data that I need.

Comment: you might need to create a format file first, so it exports the data in the right datatype, then use the same format file to do the import.  BTW, TDE will encrypt data at rest (db data/log/backup file) not in transit.

Comment: grabbed an example of a varbinary formatfile file but now my files are completely empty.

C:\temp>bcp.exe "select fileContent from [DBNAME].dbo.TableName where ID = 23" queryout Testfile.csv -T -S"MyServerName" -f formatfile.fmt

Comment: Below is what is in my format file

9.0
1
1  SQLBINARY 0 0 "" 1 fileContent ""